# How to disable MongoDB deprecation warnings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I use Node with Monk, a simple library for MongoDB. It doesn't have `insertOne` and so on. And it's totally annoying to get a deprecation warning on each `insert`. Does MongoDB have an option to disable deprecation warnings?

```
(node:17737) DeprecationWarning: collection.insert is deprecated. Use insertOne, insertMany or bulkWrite instead.
```

Comment: What do you mean deprecation warnings? Please could you add the warning message to your question. It would give more clarity

Comment: It seems to be an ongoing issue with this library: https://github.com/Automattic/monk/issues/276

Comment: not a monk's problem. deprecation warning applied

Comment: As the message suggests, did you try insertOne or insertMany?

Comment: MonkJS has no such methods

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your node code (and lots of time has passed) but for future answer searchers - some mongoose methods can receive a SaveOptions object.

ie. when using `collection.save` you can pass this in like so:

```
doc.save({ suppressWarning: true })
```

If possible - it's better to "fix" the warnings by moving on from the deprecated apis to the recommended ones.